# Python Rolling Mean of Dataframe row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

So basically I just need advice on how to calculate a 24 month rolling mean over each row of a dataframe.  Every row indicates a particular city, and the columns are the respective sales for that month.  If anyone could help me figure this out, it would be much appreciated

Edit: Clearly I failed to explain myself properly. I know that pandas has a rolling method built in. The problem is that I don't want to take the moving average of a singular column, I want to take it of columns in a row.

Sample Dataset

State - M1 - M2 - M3 - M4 - ..... - M48

UT  -    40 - 20 -  30 -  60  -.....         60

CA  -    30 - 60 -  20  - 40  -.....         70

So I want to find the rolling average for each states most recent 24 months (M24-M48 columns)

What I've tried:

```
Data['24_Month_Moving_Average'] = Data.rolling(window=24, win_type='triang', min_periods=1, axis=1).mean()
```

error:  Wrong number of items passed 139, placement implies 1

edit 2, Sample Dataset:

```
Data = pd.Dataframe({'M1':[1, 2], 'M2':[3,5], 'M3':[5,6]}, index = ['UT', 'CA'])

# need code that will add column that is the rolling 24 month average for each state
```

[Picture of Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQFeA.jpg)

Comment: Provide a sample data ... pandas has the rolling() https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

Comment: `pandas.rolling_mean`? Did you search at all?

Comment: Please see my edited post

Comment: Get a sample dataset that we actually can use ... what you provided is not usable for us, then provide the desired output .

Comment: Okay, I've added a picture of the dataframe

Comment: Please don't post pictures for the data or code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions `rolling()` with `mean()` and specify the parameters you want `window, min_periods` as follow:

```
df.col1.rolling(n, win_type='triang', min_periods=1).mean()
```

Don't know what shoudl eb your expected outptu but listing a sample to show with the apply() for each row generate the rolling, make the `state` column the index for your dataframe, hope it helps:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [6, 1, 2, 20, 4],'C': [1, 1, 2, 30, 4],'D': [10, 1, 2, 5, 4]})

def test_roll(data):
    return(data.rolling(window=2, win_type='triang', min_periods=1, axis=0).mean())


print(df.apply(test_roll, axis=1))
```

[pandas.DataFrame.rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html)

Comment: right, but my problem lies in the fact that I don't want the rolling mean over a column. I want to do the rolling mean over multiple columns in each row

Comment: Just change the axis=1  for columns and if you want to do for each state with an apply() function or for loop